# Promise resolves immediately while it should wait for the timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, resolve

I started learning about JavaScript Promises today. I'm working in a NodeJS environment with multiple modules. Just to get an better understanding how a promise works, I've made a test function that resolves the promise after 5 seconds. This is what I did:

```
const utils = require('./utils');

const labels = {
  init(req, res, next) {
    utils.loopDates(options).then(build.init(options, req, res, next));
  }
};
```

In the `utils.loopDates()` function I do the following:

```
const utils = {
  loopDates(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      options.test = 'test';
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(options)
      }, 5000)
    });
  }
}

module.exports = utils;
```

This is my understanding of what should happen; the promise resolves after 5 seconds and then the `build.init` function fires. But what actually happens is that the `build.init` function fires immediately. The promise seems to ignore the timeout.

It could be that my understanding of Promises is wrong, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Hope someone can help me out.

Cheers

Comment: `.then()` isn’t magic. `.then(build.init(options, req, res, next))` calls `build.init` and passes its return value to `.then()` like any other function.

Comment: use `.then(()=>{build.init(options, req, res, next)})` to wrap your function

Comment: thanks @Apolo now it works!